# Field API field_schema for text field error

Tags: 7, entities

I've built a custom field using the Field API. I've defined the following element:

```
  $element['tabcontent'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Tab content'),
    '#type' => 'text_format',
    '#required' => $required,
    // use #default_value to prepopulate the element
    // with the current saved value
    '#default_value' => isset($item['tabcontent']) ? $item['tabcontent'] : '',
    '#tree' => true,
    '#rows' => 10,
    '#format' => 'full_html',
    '#base_type' => 'textarea',
  );
```

I've got the following code in the install file:

```
function tabfield_field_schema($field) 
{
 
  $columns = array(
    'tabtitle' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 255, 'not null' => TRUE),
    'tabcontent' => array('type' => 'text','not null' => TRUE,'size' => 'normal','description' => 'Question prompt','length' => '1000'  ),
  );


  return array(
    'columns' => $columns,
    'indexes' => array(),
  );
}
```

However, I get the following error when saving a new node:

> Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array
> given in _media_generate_tagMap() (line 186 of
> C:\Workspace\RnD\drupal1\sites\all\modules\media\includes\media.filter.inc).
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
> _media_generate_tagMap() (line 187 of C:\Workspace\RnD\drupal1\sites\all\modules\media\includes\media.filter.inc).
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array
> given in check_plain() (line 1572 of
> C:\Workspace\RnD\drupal1\includes\bootstrap.inc).
>
> PDOException:
> SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136
> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1: INSERT INTO
> {field_data_field_tab} (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, bundle,
> delta, language, field_tab_tabtitle, field_tab_tabcontent) VALUES
> (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
> :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
> :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5,
> :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7_value,
> :db_insert_placeholder_7_format); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0]
> => node [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 17 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 17 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => tabbed_page
> [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => und
> [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => ss [:db_insert_placeholder_7_value] =>
> ss [:db_insert_placeholder_7_format] => full_html ) in
> field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (line 448 of
> C:\Workspace\RnD\drupal1\modules\field\modules\field_sql_storage\field_sql_storage.module).

Comment: I'm getting the same error from a save on a textarea field on a form that used to work :(

Answer (score 1):

This is because your value suppose to be `string`, however you given `array` as per these errors:

> Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in _media_generate_tagMap()
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in check_plain()

Since you're sending array, the **column count doesn't match** in your SQL query.

This is what you're sending:

```
INSERT INTO {field_data_field_tab} (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, language, field_tab_tabtitle, field_tab_tabcontent)
VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7_value, :db_insert_placeholder_7_format);
Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 17 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 17 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => tabbed_page [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => und [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => ss [:db_insert_placeholder_7_value] => ss [:db_insert_placeholder_7_format] => full_html )
```

which can be broke down into:

- Fields: *entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, language, field_tab_tabtitle, field_tab_tabcontent*
- Placeholders: *:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7_value, :db_insert_placeholder_7_format*

So you've 8 fields, but 9 placeholders.

#### Fix

To fix it, you've to check passed value of `$item['tabcontent']` and make it a string. For example:

```
'#default_value' => !empty($item['tabcontent']['value']) ? $item['tabcontent']['value'] : '',
```

---

See also:

- [Errors when using a field of '#type' => 'text_format'](https://www.drupal.org/node/1943886)

Answer (score 0):

I only got it to work by using a combination of this approach + the variable_get() method.

[image]

[image]

[image: The final code looks like this. Notice the format coming from the field as well]